# force:recordEdit is not working with Secure Client-Side Caching

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am using force:recordEdit in my component to edit the record.

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
    <force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</div>
```

and then i am using a button to save the record which will fire recordSave event to save my record.

```
<ui:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" label="Save" press="{!c.saveRec}"/>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
saveRec : function(component, event, helper){
    //Open modal
    component.set("v.isLoading", true);

    //Save the record
    component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave").fire();              
    
},
```

This functionality is working perfectly if i uncheck **Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance**. But if i select this checkbox, component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave") is returning null. And ultimately the fire() is failing as it is not able to recognize the event.

> [Cannot read property 'fire' of null]

What i understood with this checkbox is it adds data caching in the browser to avoid additional call to server for performance improvement. I have deselected this checkbox to avoid mutliple times refresh to reflect the changes during development. :)

Does it mean force:recordEdit uses clientside caching and how it works ? Salesforce doesn't recommend deselecting this checkbox as per [this](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_lightning_secure_cache.htm)
if there is no exception to our client.
Can someone help me to understand this concept ?

Comment: Similar I asked here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188150/e-recordsave-event-behaving-weird-in-lightning-component-returning-null-sometim

Comment: Did you find answer for this ? @thatherahere